# React Native Expo-Print printToFileAsync without saving file

Tags: react-native, pdf, pdf-generation, file-conversion

I am currently using Expo-Print's function PrintToFileAsync to create a PDF file from an HTML string, and then transferring its base64 representation via an API. The issue is that the PDF, which is created and stored in the app's cache, contains sensitive information which should never be stored in the cache. I am currently just deleting the PDF file once the base64 has been transferred but this is not idea.

Is there a way to convert from HTML to PDF to base64 without saving the PDF in the middle?

Comment: The process currently goes HTML > PDF > Base64 representation of the PDF. I am looking for a way to go HTML > Base64 representation of the PDF.